# Flutter: ios/native_add.podspec File is not exist

Tags: xcode, flutter, opencv, dart

I want to run OpenCV with flutter. First of all , i try to the FFI library to bind to native code.

Flutter Dev says "  On iOS, you need to tell Xcode to statically link the file:

In Xcode, open Runner.xcworkspace.
Add the C/C++/Objective-C/Swift source files to the Xcode project "

But i don't have a file name that ' Runner.xcworkspace "

[My XCode Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGPkL.jpg)

[My AndroidStudio Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lczNG.png)

Its very hard to run opencv or c++ code in Flutter. I am working on it for 3 days and there is no improvement.

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the guide on flutter.dev [Binding to native code using dart:ffi](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop) it is because you created a plugin template and as such the iOS folder only contains plugin-specific files.
To find the iOS folder you are looking for, please open the "example" folder that was also created when you made the project and open the iOS folder therein.

Answer (score 0):

for run OpenCV with flutter and with native code using ffi, you can do with this way:

**iOS**: in Podfile add next line to target

```
pod 'OpenCV', '~> 4.3'
```

In Build Settings -> Library Search Paths add recursive path

```
"$(SRCROOT)/Pods/OpenCV"
```

For debug running you can add opencv.framework to your project directory

**Android**: for android you have two methods

1. *native*: donwloading SDK for Android (.java extensions) like most  tutorials on google...
2. *c compiled*: folder `android/app/build.gradle` add next parts

```
    android {
        ...
        defaultConfig {
            ...
            externalNativeBuild {
                        cmake {
                            // Enabling exceptions, RTTI
                            // And setting C++ standard version
                            cppFlags '-frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11'
            
                            // Shared runtime for shared libraries
                            arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                        }
                    }
            ...
        }
        ...
        //external c++ plugin
        externalNativeBuild{
            cmake{
                path "<pathtoyour>/CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
        ...
    }
```

File **CMakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1) 

set( OpenCV_DIR "<path>/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni" )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
message(STATUS "OpenCV libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")

add_library( <youe binary> SHARED <path to your c++ or c file> )
target_link_libraries( <youe binary> ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```